# GIT keep branch specific files - always ignore specific files

Tags: git

I am trying  to keep  file which holds branch specific information (version).

after adding the file i update the `.gitgnore` with the file path.

The problem : when i merge the branch the file is  getting merge into the destination branch.

I have tried the following:
[How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Using `git rm --cached <file>` delete the file

Adding The file using `--force` causes the file to be tracked even if it is ignored in `.gitignore`

is there a way to keep a file on specific branch ?

thanks

Comment: Why is the file being ignored if it is branch specific?

Comment: using the version for specific branch build - in order to keep the version of the build with out versioning the sources , also i wish to use this method to keep githooks for specific usage

Comment: "Adding The file" why is it being added if you want to ignore it?

Comment: i need the file once - to set the version - after updating it - i need to ignore it

Comment: I'm confused. It's not possible to both track a file _and_ ignore it

Comment: i thought after i add the file to .gitgnore in its current state it will be ignored from this time and forward

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### There are no such thing as branch-specific files

Git has:

- commits
- which contain files
- and which are found via branch names

but:

- two or more branch names can specify a single commit, and
- you can add and delete branch names at any time

so since *branches* don't really exist as a thing—they're completely changeable at all times—there literally can't be any branch-specific files.  There are only commit-specific files.

#### You cannot ignore tracked files

In a comment, you say:

> i thought after i add the file to .gitgnore in its current state it will be ignored from this time and forward

This is not the case.

Git does not ever really *ignore* files, and `.gitignore` is the wrong name for what goes into this file.  However, a *correct* name would be something like `.git-do-not-complain-if-these-files-are-untracked-and-if-they-are-untracked-and-I-use-an-en-masse-add-command-do-not-make-them-tracked`.  While that's what listing files here *does*, it's a ridiculous name for the file, so the Git guys chose `.gitignore`: an inaccurate name, but one that's short and people can actually type in.

#### How to understand all of this

The trick to making this all make sense is to change your point of view.  Those new to Git think that Git stores files, and uses branches to do that.  Both of these ideas are wrong!  The things Git stores are *commits*.

Now, commits do *contain* files.  But it's an all-or-nothing deal: you either do have a commit—and thus *all* of its files—or you don't, and thus you don't have any of its files.  The files stored inside each commit—each commit holds a full snapshot of *every* file; we'll come back to this idea in a moment—is stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  Nothing but Git can even *read* these files, and nothing—not even Git itself—can *write* to them.  This means that the committed files are entirely useless for getting any work done.

Because *committed* files are useless (for getting work done that is), Git has to *extract* the committed files to a work-area.  In this work area, the extracted files are expanded out to their normal everyday form.  *These* are the files that you can see and work with.  They are ordinary files.  The only thing special about them is that Git *extracted* them from some commit, at some point.

Because they're *copies* that have literally been copied out of a commit, **these files are not, in fact, in Git at all!**  They're just there for you to use, however you like.  They are *your* files, in other words.  Git's files are for Git, and yours are for you: Git just copies some out, sometimes, when you tell it to.

Besides the stored files—stored in this special Git-ified form—each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes stuff like the author name and email address.  We won't go into any detail here, but this metadata is crucial to Git: Git can't work without it.

The point of all of this is to see how the files you see and work with *are not Git's files*.  They aren't in Git, so you can do anything you want with them.  This is mostly a good thing—but since they're not in Git, you can also add *more* files to your work area, that didn't even *come out* of Git in the first place.  **These extra, added files are untracked files.**  There's a bit of mechanism here, and it's important to know about.

#### Git's index is how Git knows about files

Your working tree, where you have your files, is pretty simple, if you've been using computers and files for a while.  It's just like any other set of files that you can work with.  You can create and destroy files here all you like.  Git just set up some files initially for you, by *checking out* some commit.  Git used a *branch name* to *find* that commit and we'll come back to this idea later, but for now, we just note that your initial set of files probably came out of a commit just now.  (If not, they came out of a commit some time ago.)

This means there are *two copies* of each of these files:

- One, a read-only copy, is saved in the *current commit*, in a safe form that will be accessible forever (or as long as the commit continues to exist).
- The other one is a regular file that lets you do whatever you want.

But, in between the commits—which store read-only, compressed and de-duplicated files in an internal Git-only format—and your working tree, where you have these ordinary files, Git adds a *third copy*—well, *sort of* a copy—of each of these files.  This third "copy" is stored in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  The three terms all refer to the same thing.  What's really in here is the file's name and some other information, including information about a pre-de-duplicated copy.  When the file just came out of some commit, that de-duplicated copy *is* the frozen-for-all-time copy in the repository.

Because that copy is frozen, *all commits* that use the *same version* of that file get to share it.  So does Git's index.  So it doesn't really take any space to speak of.  That's the de-duplication in action.

If you *change the work-tree copy*, you'll need to get Git to update its index copy.  **This is what the `git add` command is about.**  When you run `git add` on a file you've changed, Git:

- compresses the file down to the special format;
- checks to see if it already has that one anywhere, and if so, uses the frozen one, updating Git's index;
- otherwise, has the frozen one ready to go into the next commit, and hence updates its index

—and this means that after `git add`, the index is ready to go: you can make a *new* commit that has the updated file.  All the *existing* files are still there, in Git's index.  So what's going on is that the index has, *at all times*, the *next* commit in it, ready to go.  The *next* commit is initially the same as the *current commit*.

If you `git add` a file that *isn't* in the index yet, Git compresses the file down into the frozen format and creates a new entry in Git's index, for the new file.  If you `git rm` a file, Git *removes* the file from *both its index and your work-tree*, and now the next commit will completely lack the file.  In this way, the index remains the proposed next commit.

If you remove a file from your work-tree, and then run `git add` on that file, Git simply removes the index entry.  The frozen file in the commit(s) is untouched by this process.  That's the case for the `git rm` as well: it only removes the *index* entry, not the underlying file data.  That underlying file data can never be changed at all, and as long as some commit(s) are using it, it can't be removed either.  So, again, the index holds the proposed next commit.

What this means is that `git commit` merely needs to snapshot the index.  Everything *in* the index is already in the frozen format, ready to go: it just has to be packaged up into a new commit.  The set of files that go in this new commit are precisely those files that are in Git's index, at that time.

What you do in between `git checkout` and `git commit`, in your *work-tree*, is not really relevant here.  But `git add` copies *from* your work-tree to Git's index, and that does matter.  So changing work-tree copies of files is useful, as long as you also `git add` these changes.

If you *don't* `git add` these changes, a work-tree file that came out of your current commit, and therefore is now "out of date" in the index (by comparison to what's in your work-tree), remains "out of date" there in a *new* commit, if you make one.  That's fine: sometimes that's what you want!  It's a bit annoying to have `git status` tell you about these *changes not staged for commit*, but there is nothing wrong with this.  However, note that if you run `git add .`, the file is *already in the index* and will be updated in the index.  An en-masse operation like `git add .` or `git add *` or `git add -u` will see that the work-tree copy is updated as compared to the index copy, and will update the index copy from the work-tree, as usual.

What this means is that it's very important to know what's in the index.  There are no user-oriented Git commands to list out the files in the index, but there *is* one that's not *user*-oriented: you can run `git ls-files` (use `git ls-files --stage` to get more detail; `git ls-files` by itself just lists the names of files that are in Git's index; see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) for details).

#### Untracked files are those that are not in the index

Your work-tree is *yours*.  Because of this, you can create files in it that are not yet in Git's index.  The `git status` command calls these files *untracked*.  So if the commit you checked out has no file named `F`, and you create a new file named `F`, you now have an untracked file named `F`.

You can also use `git rm --cached` to *remove* a file copy from Git's index, without removing it from your work-tree.  Suppose Git extracted some commit, and that commit came with a file named `F`.  This means there are currently three copies of `F`: the read-only copy in the current commit, the copy in Git's index ready to go into the *next* commit, and the copy in your work-tree.  If you now run `git rm --cached F`, Git *removes* the index copy of `F`.  The read-only copy is still in the current commit, but your *proposed next commit*—the stuff in the index—*lacks* file `F`.  A new commit you make now will have no file `F`.

Either way, file `F` is now in your work-tree, but not in Git's index.  **That's what makes the file untracked.**  Because it's not in Git's index, it won't be in the *next* commit.  If there's an `F` in the *current commit*, the *difference* between the current and next commits is going to include the instruction: "delete file `F`".  If there's no `F` in the current commit, there isn't going to be a difference concerning file `F`, because it's not going to be in the current or next commit.

So an untracked file is very simple: it's a file that you have in your work-tree, but that is not in Git's index.  But the way the file *became* untracked is less simple: maybe it's untracked because it wasn't committed, or maybe it's untracked because you removed it from Git's index.  You get some control over this, after all.

By contrast, a file that *is* in Git's index is *tracked*.  Maybe it's there because it was in the commit you checked out.  Or, maybe it's there because you ran `git add` to copy it into Git's index.  You get some control over this too.

But you do need to remember that when you *switch* to *some other* commit, Git is going to empty its index of *these* files, from *this* commit, and fill the index instead with *those* files, from the other commit you're switching to.  So if you have some tracked or untracked files now, that situation could change, because the index's contents can change with a new `git checkout`.

(Some variants of `git reset`, and the new-since-2.23 `git restore` command, also affect Git's index.  It's a big and important data structure!  It's where *new commits* come from.  So it's always a good idea to think about it now and then.)

#### This gets us back to `.gitignore`

Listing a file in `.gitignore` mainly does the two things I listed earlier:

- It keeps `git status` from *saying* that the file is untracked, when it's untracked.

  Note that `git status` might not have said anything about it when it's tracked either.  So you can't really tell if a file is tracked or not just from `git status`, at least, not in all cases:

  - If `git status` says some file is *staged for commit* or *not staged for commit*, that file is definitely tracked.
  - If `git status` says some file is *untracked*, that file is definitely untracked.
  - But if `git status` says nothing about a file, we don't know its tracked/untracked status.
- And, it keeps `git add .` or other similar "add many files" commands from *adding* the file, if it's currently untracked.
- But if some file is already tracked, the entry in `.gitignore` has no effect.

#### A special trick (try not to use it)

There is a special trick you can use, but it's not designed for this.  Suppose you have some file `F` that *is* tracked and is committed.  You make some change to your working tree copy of `F`, but you want to be sure you don't accidentally `git add` this change and copy it back into Git's index: you want Git's index to *keep the old copy*.

What you can do here is run:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree F
```

to set, on the index entry for file `F`, the *skip worktree* flag.  This tells Git to *pretend* that the index copy is always in sync with the work-tree copy.  A `git add .` won't copy `F` back into Git's index, so that the old copy will remain in Git's index.

This flag is *meant* for something Git calls *sparse checkout*.  If you start setting it here, you won't be able to use the sparse checkout feature properly later.  It also has a bunch of weird side effects, because Git sometimes needs to change out the index copy of the file.  I won't go into all the details here: they get complicated.

#### How branch names work

Without going into all the details, the metadata associated with each commit lets Git string commits together into chains.  These chains all point backwards (for reasons we won't go into), so if we draw them, we get a picture that looks like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the *last* commit in the chain.  The commit has some hash ID, which is how Git actually finds the commit; you'll see these hash IDs in `git log` output, for instance.  But hash IDs are useless to humans because they're so big and ugly and impossible to get right.  So, while *Git* uses the hash IDs, *we* don't.  We use *branch names*.

A branch name simply holds the hash ID of the *last* (most-recent / newest) commit that we'd like to say is "on the branch".  When we have a single, simple chain of commits, we get something like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch
```

Once we start making lots of branches and different commits *on* these branches, though, we get divergence:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

There are a bunch of interesting things about this.  Two of them are:

- The commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*.
- The name `br1` selects commit `J`; the name `br2` selects commit `L`.

This means that `git checkout br1` will fill in both Git's index and your work-tree from the files that are in commit `J`.  Using `git checkout br2`, you'll replace those files with the ones from commit `L`.  As long as the set of file *names* in `J` and `L` remain the same, any *untracked files* in your work-tree, that aren't in either `J` or `L`, are undisturbed as you switch between commits `J` and `L`.

But the things about branch names are:

- they *move*; and
- we can create and destroy new ones at any time.

Let's take a look at creating a new *name* for commit `J` right now.  We start with `git checkout br1`, to *select* commit `J`, and update our drawing a bit:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The special name `HEAD` is how Git knows *which branch name we're using*.

Now let's create a new name, `br3`, using `git branch br3`.  The picture changes a bit:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD), br3
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

There are now *two* names for commit `J`.  If we create a new commit now, the new commit we make gets a new, unique hash ID, but we'll just call it `N` for `N`ew (I like to reserve `M` for `M`erge here):

```
               N   <-- br1 (HEAD)
              /
          I--J   <-- br3
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

What Git did is to snapshot the files in the index and add appropriate metadata, and thus create commit `N`, and then *write `N`'s actual hash ID into the current branch name*.

Commit `J` is now the *last* commit on `br3`, but is on both `br1` and `br3`.  Commits up through `H` are on *all three branches*.

#### This is why there is no such thing as a branch-specific file

The files that are in commit `J` do not, and cannot, change, as we create new commits.  Yet commit `J` *used to be* the tip commit of branch `br1`.  It's now the tip commit of branch `br3`, with branch `br1` having moved on to select commit `N`.

The files in `J` *can* be specific to commit `J`.  You just put the right contents into Git's index, then run `git commit`, when you *make* commit `J`.  But they can't be specific to some branch name: the names move around, and someday commit `J` can be on more than one branch.  For instance, we can now run `git checkout br2` and then run `git merge br3`.  The `checkout br2` step does this:

```
               N   <-- br1
              /
          I--J   <-- br3
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

The `merge` command finds the *merge base* (commit `H`) and then combines work done on the `H`-to-`L` leg with work done on the `H`-to-`J` leg, to produce a new *merge commit* `M`:

```
               N   <-- br1
              /
          I--J   <-- br3
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br2 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

The branch name `br2` now selects the new merge commit, and this merge commit reaches back to *both* commits `L` *and* `J`, so that commit `J` is now on all three branches.  (So is commit `I`.)

The set of branches that "contain", or *reach*, a commit—by starting at the tip and working backwards—changes dynamically in a Git repository.  A commit can be, and many are, on more than one branch.

Comment: @galsi please please read this answer. It's long and may take a while, but it'll be worth it.

Comment: @torek thanks for the detailed answer , it is a must read for any GIT starter

Answer (score 1):

While I adore @torek's detailed answer above (points all around!), I'd like to share my solutions to OP's original question—namely,

> ***How to keep a file which holds branch specific information (e.g. version)***

## A: Define per-file [Merge Strategies with Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies)

This is probably my cleanest answer.

I'll assume that the file you want to be immune to incoming merges is a plaintext file called `VERSION`.

1. Start with a clean index.

   `git commit` or `git restore --staged --all`
2. Append the following to a `.gitattributes` file in the repo directory containing `VERSION`.

   ```bash
   echo "VERSION merge=ours" >> .gitattributes
   ```
3. Sanity check w/ `git check-attr`:

   ```bash
   git check-attr --all VERSION
   ## Expected output: ##
   # VERSION: merge: ours
   ```
4. Stage and commit `.gitattributes`.
5. **For this technique to actually work**, you and any other maintainers will need to run the following:

   ```bash
   git config --global merge.ours.driver true
   # or --local or wherever ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
   ```

Now, whenever **merging** into a branch containing this `.gitattributes` definition, the file `VERSION` will never get clobbered.

---

- Note 1: Merging such branches upstream—particularly to histories *without* this `.gitattributes` entry—will likely include this `VERSION` file in the merge (potentially causing a conflict) *before* our special attribute can be applied.