# How to keep different files versions from a project in different branches?

Tags: git

I Want to have a favicon.png with a flower in development branch but the same favicon.png having a fish in the main branch (just as example) but keeping all the other files chanes synced with every merge or rebase.

Comment: Does your "every merge or rebase" change the favicon?

Comment: You can't (quite) have a branch-specific file. Give up on that idea and use some other approach, e.g., not using the name `favicon.png` here at all but rather `favicon.fish.png` and `favicon.flower.png`. Then when you *deploy* some branch, copy or rename the file into place as needed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53819482/1256452) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65599226/1256452) as well.